# Calling Share point REST API from Angular Application

Tags: angular

Scenario:

From Angular application, we are using HTTP.get() in order to hit SHARE POINT rest api url.
Share point URL is public url and can be accessed by any one.
Result: We are getting 401 unauthorized error.

If we hit the same url in the web browser, we were able to get the response with out any problem.

Observations:

when we hit the rest api in normal web browser, we are getting TYPE as 'document'.
when we hit the rest api with in Angular Application. the request is going as TYPE 'XHR'.
Anyone please help us on this issue.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: It may be that you're not including the users credentials with the request which could cause trouble for the windows authentication usually setup with SharePoint - maybe try including new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });

Comment: @Niladri, This is how i am using in the code.
`

 return this.http.get('http://uaturl:8080/sites/getUser/_api/web/currentUser')
            .pipe(map((response: any) => {
                console.log(response);
            }), catchError((e) => {
                //console.log();
            }));
`

Comment: @kishoreaoe you need to send the credential for sharepoint in header or using `withCredentials`

Comment: @Niladri, You are savior.!! After adding this i could able to get it.. thanks alot.!

Comment: @kishoreaoe You are welcome, Should I post this as answer? `withCredentials` is the recommended way

Comment: @niladri, Yeah Please go ahead :)

Comment: @niladri, When i used withCredentials as true, i have 200 response from sharepoint url how ever i am getting CORS error as stated below.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'sharepoint url' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding odata=verbose to your header?

```
{
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
```

Comment: Yes, We have tried by adding all the possible headers. Still it is giving 401 un-authorized while hitting the sharepoint rest url.

Comment: have a look to this article, hope it's helpful

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52112/401-unauthorized-when-connecting-from-outside